# Discord.py Deleting DMChannels

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

im trying to delete a discord DMChannel on clients account logging with `client.login("ùser token")`. But im stuck at deleting the channel.I have read the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member_update#discord.DMChannel.type) but i didnt find a solution. I searched about this but i only found purging DMChannel messages but that is not what i want. *My goal is deleting all **DMChannels** on clients account*.

**MyCode**

```py
import discord


token = "Hidden_Token"
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    print("Bot is Ready!")
    print(f"Logged in as '{client.user}'")
    await client.private_channels[0].delete()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        client.run(token, bot=False)
    except discord.errors.LoginFailure:
        print(f"Login failure: improper token in '{token}'")
```

**Error Message**

```py
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/fun.py", line 13, in on_ready
    await client.private_channels[0].delete()
AttributeError: 'DMChannel' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "delete dm channel"? That's not really possible...

Comment: There is a X near the dm channel on discord app with normal use. İ mean closing it

Comment: For all I know, the bot cannot (and should not be able to) interact with the user's DMs. They'll have to close the DM channel on their own

Comment: I agree with Thaler here.  If you are trying to delete the user's DMs then you are probably out of luck.  If this isn't what you are trying to accomplish we may need some clarification on what exactly you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: You can't really do that with discord.py. Discord.py is used for bots only. Apparently you are trying to accomplish self-bot. *This is against ToS and shouldn't be done. You will get your account disabled*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can't delete a DM. You can only purge the message YOU sent up. Check out the official discord api docs, you can't delete a DM channel.